# getting Client DOM Code Injection security issue in lightning controller

Tags: lightning, security-review, security-scanner

In scanning, I got Client DOM Code Injection security issue in lightning controller for below section:
window.addEventListener("message", function(event) {
**var message = event.data;**
}, false);

I tried replacing the above line by
**var message = "<%= Encode.forJavaScript(event.data) %>";** but it is behaving as String.
Can anyone suggest me what could be the solution to fix client dom code injection.

Comment: Does using var message = JSON.parse(event.data); work in your case?

Comment: No, it is not working.